# Unable to locate an element though able to assert the same element

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am able to assert an element (present on the navigated new page) when page navigated to new page successfully, however when trying to 'click' the same element facing an issue as "NoSuchElementException".

```
FAILED with exception 
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such 
element: Unable to locate element: method: xpath, 
selector:"//div...}
```

I tried to find if this element is in iframe using below code, the log shows there is no iframe exists on the page, also the same element can be asserted successfully.

```
List<WebElement> elements = 
driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));

log.info("elements iframe is" + elements);
```

log shows:

```
elements iframe is[[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP 
(b39f02ba258fd8b71c77)] -> tag name: 
iframe]]
```

Tried by putting hard sleep, the page clearly shows this element but always getting NoSuchElementException.

HTML of this element:

```
<div class="assign-button-text" xpath="1">Go and Attend</div>
```

XPATH:

```
//div[contains(text(),'Go and Attend')]
```

Comment: Could you try to use FluentWait instead of findElement?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have used explicit wait already still faced issue. Now, it is resolved by using with 'id' locator than with xpath like driver.findElement(By.id("Go")).click();